# How to remove an element by id?

Tags: javascript

I just try a tutorial here on how to upload multiple form - http://www.maheshchari.com/multifile-upload/

Basically, it have a link to add a new input when it clicked. My question is, how to add another link to REMOVE the input?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: That site is all kinds of broke :(

Comment: can you post the code what u r using ?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove an element that you know the ID of using:

```
function removeById(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);

  // A bit of robustness helps...
  if (element && element.parentNode) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have doubt. actually he asked the question "My question is, how to add another link to REMOVE the input?" but you answer is for remove the element.  is that right answer what Zhaf looking ?

Comment: @balaphp - dunno, just figured I'd show how to do it, implementation is the OP's problem. Perhaps filling in one detail will lead to a coherent follow–up question? Ever the optimist. :-)

Answer (score 0):

please update you function add_file_field to

```
var file_counter = 0;
function add_file_field(){
    file_counter++;
    var container=document.getElementById('file_container');
    var file_field=document.createElement('input');
    file_field.name='images[]';
    file_field.type='file';
    file_field.id='file_'+file_counter;
    container.appendChild(file_field);
    var remove_field = document.createElement('a');
    remove_field.href = "javascript:removeById('"+'file_'+file_counter+"');removeById('"+'remove_field_'+file_counter+"');";
    remove_field.innerHTML = "Remove')";
    remove_field.id = 'remove_field_'+file_counter;
    var br_field=document.createElement('br');
    container.appendChild(br_field);
}
```

this create a 
and also add function removeById in you javascript so that when any one clicks on remove button then the file type field will remove. which is posted in previous post also

```
function removeById(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  // A bit of robustness helps...
  if (element && element.parentNode) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple,

```
document.getElementById("_id").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("_id"));
```